# Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\php\\ext\\php_pdo.dll - how to fix it

Tags: php, windows-10, apache2.4

I search several days in internet, tried several time to update php.ini , restarting apache .... could not find any idea more what I should look for / change by now.

In eclipse when I debug a PHP script

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=' .$dbhost . '; dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass); 
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I get:

> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'c:\php\ext\php_pdo.dll' - % 1 is not a valid Win32 application.

were to find the proper DLL for PHP7.1 - MYsql ?

please can someone help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that this error is related to eclipse itself, do you have the same issue in terminal for example or on your http server?

Comment: - I have the same issue on http server

- In Apache24 log (error) I have following message when  restart the server 
"PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\php\\ext\\php_pdo.dll' - %1 ist keine zul\xef\xbf\xbdssige Win32-Anwendung.\r\n in Unknown on line 0"
it is in german (meaning isn*t a valid Win32 application)